# Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I am making a macro that will search though a list and find all the entries in a column that has spectraseven at the first. This will be to copy these records to sheet for each entry.

With the code so far it fails with:

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

```
Sub testWild()
startCell = 0
Dim FoundCell As Range
Dim LastCell As Range
Dim FirstAddr As String
cellRange = "A1:A20"
topCount = startCell
With Range("A1:A20")
Set LastCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
End With
Dim findString As String 
findString = "spectraseven*"
 Set FoundCell = Range(cellRange).Find(what:=findString, after:=LastCell)



If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
FirstAddr = FoundCell.Address
End If
Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
    Debug.Print FoundCell.Address
Set FoundCell = Range(cellRange).FindNext(after:=FoundCell)

Count = FoundCell.Row
    Set FoundCell = Range(cellRange).FindNext(after:=FoundCell)

 --->   Sheets(1).Range("a" & topCount) = Sheets(1).Range("e" & Count)
    topCount = topCount + 1



If FoundCell.Address = FirstAddr Then
    Exit Do
End If
Loop
End Sub
```

The arrow points to the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `startCell` equal to 0.

You then set `topCount` = `startCell`

You don't do anything else with `topCount` before starting the loop.

Therefore, this:

```
Sheets(1).Range("a" & topCount) = Sheets(1).Range("e" & Count)
```

Evaluates to

```
Sheets(1).Range("a0") = Sheets(1).Range("e" & FoundCell.Row)
```

There is no such thing as cell A0.  Try starting `startCell` at 1.

Comment: thanks. I guess i am to used to other programming languages that start at 0.

Comment: to clarify, numeric (integer, long, double, single) variables start at 0 in VBA as well, however, when referencing cells directly in Excel like `Range("A1")` they start at 1. Also, when referencing cells in a range, you have to use 1 base as well, so `Range("A1:A10").Cells(1,1).Address = $A$1`